# Permission denied to call method ModalContentWindow.postMessage in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, youtube-api, postmessage, google-api-js-client

I am working with the [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/). Google recommends loading the libs using:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=googleApiClientReady">
```

It works fine but when I load the script like this into a modal window in Firefox (it's got to be this way. I can't control the way my widget is called by Sitecore) it fails with:

Error: **Permission denied** for https://accounts.google.com to call method **ModalContentWindow.postMessage**

It comes from within internal callbacks that Google's `client.js` calls when loaded even if I omit the `?onload` part.

Works fine loaded into a standalone tab. IE and Chrome do fine either way.

Is there a good way to make it work in FF modal window? (I am running 27.0.1 if it matters)

**UPDATE**: I worked around it by calling YouTube Data API HTTP endpoints directly. I am still wondering though what's up with that [postMessage() thingy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) in FF's modal window and whether it's known to the authors of Google's `client.js`.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that Firefox has policy for capability.policy.default.Window.postMessage.get but it doesn't have policy capability.policy.default.ModalContentWindow.postMessage.get.
There is two way to solve this issue.

- add pref for Firefox pref("capability.policy.default.ModalContentWindow.postMessage.get", "allAccess");
- instead of loading the script into a modal window directly put it inside iframe. iframe would have class Window.

BTW I faced this issue in FF28. In FF31 everything works fine.